# ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronization, abaddressbook

I built an iphone app that syncs with the iphone address book.

with some users, the contact list has "linked contacts" or unified or merged contacts, they appear at the bottom. so some users have one person as the main contact and more linked contacts for the same/or other contact in the exchange server or mobileMe or whatever.

I tried running ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource with kABSourceTypeLocal but it still returned duplicate contacts when encountering contacts with linked contacts

how can I make sure I sync only the main identify without duplicates ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class with the singleton pattern.